# XWiki - users suddenly cannot log in, invalid password message even though password is correct

Tags: wiki, xwiki

For unknown reason, some of my XWiki users cannot log in. Their accounts are enabled and they are providing correct username/password, yet they receive `Error: Invalid credentials`.

We tried multiple accounts, and we are providing correct credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the issue was that we moved some users profile pages under different parent in the page tree.

After moving their profile pages back under `XWiki` page (where they are created by default), they are able to log in again.